# Get defined Route from Dto

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I've created a basic Dto Hit tracker that counts how many times a ServiceStack API is requested. What I'm trying to get now is the Route that was defined for the current Dto in the ServiceBase using Routes.Add. I can get current Url from the HttpContext, however that one is already populated with data. E.g

```
//Defined Route
/customers/{CustomerID}/orders

//From HttpContext
/customers/123456/orders
```

Is there way to get the defined route with the parameter {CustomerID} still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Route for the Request with `IRequest.GetRoute()`.

Also if you want to create a Request DTO from a path or URL you can use `Metadata.CreateRequestFromUrl()` [added in the latest v5.1 Release Notes](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.1.0#call-internal-and-external-services-from-urls).